# Is there any option in JavaScript (client side) to merge two or more ppt's into one?

Tags: javascript, merge, powerpoint, client-side-scripting

I need to merge two or more PowerPoint presentations into one via client side JavaScript. Is there any option to do that?

Comment: PPT files are made of data. You can manipulate data with programming languages. JavaScript is a programming language. So "Yes". It's probably not exactly trivial though.

Comment: Thanks. But how to do that merging, I need some coding help.
As, I got to found somewhere that it is no possible because of security issues.

Comment: Hi @Shakti, did you find anything?

Comment: @Shakti did you find any way to merge the PPTx files?